# Calculating radius of circle through chords

Tags: geometry, circles

It looks like a simple question, but for some reason I just can't figure out how to do it: I am given the following circle (see picture) and need to calculate the radius. I know how this works when you know the chord height, but not when you are given line segments as shown.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: I'm assuming the two segments are perpendicular.

Comment: @BrianTung sorry it isn't impossible.

Comment: Sorry @BrianTung should have mentioned that indeed the two line segments are perpendicular.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the  [Law of sines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines)

[image]

Let $R$ the circumradius of the triangle $ABC$
\begin{align*}
\frac{|AC|}{\sin B}&=2R\\[4pt]
\frac{\sqrt{2^2+4^2}}{\frac2{\sqrt{2^2+16^2}}}&=2R\\[4pt]
\frac{\sqrt{20}\sqrt{260}}{2}&=2R
\end{align*}

Then $R=5\sqrt{13}$.

Answer (score 2):

**Basic approach.** Draw two right triangles, and equate their hypotenuses to the radius:

[image]

Use the Pythagorean theorem.  Drawing is approximately but not perfectly to scale.

Answer (score 2):

Consider the function
$$y=\sqrt{r^2-(x-10)^2}+b$$
This defines the upper arc of a circle centred on $(10,b)$ with radius $r$. We want it to touch $(0,0)$ and $(0,20)$, and setting the equation up at either of these points yields the same result:
$$0=\sqrt{r^2-100}+b$$
$$b^2=r^2-100\tag1$$
Now we are given that $(16,2)$ is on the arc:
$$2=\sqrt{r^2-36}+b$$
$$(2-b)^2=4-4b+b^2=r^2-36\tag2$$
Subtract $(1)$ from $(2)$:
$$4-4b=64\qquad b=-15$$
Now the radius $r$ comes easily:
$$r=\sqrt{b^2+100}=5\sqrt{13}$$

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple pythagorean theorem:
[image]