# How to calculate a full circle from chord length and offset height

Tags: circles

Could anyone calculate the following problem and explain how I could solve it in the future. I need to set out a curve based on 3 points I have measured. I need to work back to the centre so I can set out from a radius. I have attached a photograph. The chord length and height are exact. The distance to the height measurement might be off. These are site measurements [circle illustration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V7u5q.jpg)

Comment: What does mean "The distance to the height measurement might be off. " ?

Comment: I measured it with a tape measure on site. The exact measurement is the length 6140. I measured out 1605mm at 4865mm along that line. I don't know if all 3 measurements can resolve themselves mathematically

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2273313/calculating-radius-of-circle-through-chords) should work (sorry for previous, deleted, comment).

Comment: Essentially have 3 points on the circumference and ghouls be able to determine both the coordinates of the center (in reference to any of the 3 points) as well as the radius.

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/q/564058/ .